# Is Goodstein theorem true in the standard model of arithmetic?

Tags: logic, model-theory

It is known that Goodstein theorem is not provable in PA, but my question is if it is know if the theorem is true in the standard model of arithmetic.

I mean, Gödel's first incompleteness theorem shows us that there are sentences in PA that are not provable (in PA) but true in the standard model of arithmetic. My question is then if Goodstein theorem is, in fact, a concrete example of the later statement.

I know there are several questions about this topic but I don't think they really answer my question.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise we would not call it a theorem.

Comment: Well, it is a theorem of ZF, but my question was if there was some argument to show that it is, in fact, true in the standard model of arithmetic, maybe with a proof like the one that shows that if the negation of a $\Pi_1$ statement is not provable in PA, then it is true in the standard model of arithmetic.

Comment: "my question was if there was some argument to show that it is, in fact, true in the standard model of arithmetic". Yes, the argument is that it is a theorem of ZF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It has pretty much the same status as Godel's sentence or Con(PA). It is not provable in PA, but it is provable in other systems generally accepted as sound (ZF or even second-order arithmetic is major overkill) and is thus generally accepted as true.

Comment: But, is there any metamatemathical proof of it (I mean, like the one that shows that if the negation of a $\Pi_1$ statement is not provable in PA, then it is true in the standard model of arithmetic), or it is just accepted as true because is provable in, for example, ZF?

Comment: @Eparoh you seem to be making a distinction between “true” and “true in the standard model of arithmetic” when there is none. If we’re being parsimonious, it’s provable in PA + a fairly transparent structural induction principle. It’s $\Pi_2$, not $\Pi_1$, so we can’t immediately jump from “it’s not refutable” to “it’s true” like we can in the case of, say, Con(PA), though I don’t really see how that’s preferable, since we need additional assumptions to show Con(PA) is not refutable, anyway.